How can I clone a git repository owned by another user without modifying the global git configuration file?
I wish to clone a git repository owned by another (trusted) user on a shared system. Simply trying to clone it without any change to the git configuration does not work because recent versions of git introduced a safety check that blocks searching git repositories owned by other users:
git clone /path/to/repo/owned/by/other ./here

fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/path/to/repo/owned/by/other'

To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory /path/to/repo/owned/by/other/.git

Running this git config command effectively fixes the problem, but (for reasons I do not care to explain here) I would like to be able to clone the repository without modifying the git config file.
The git man page talks about an option -c that lets users overwrite git config options when running git commands:
man git

...

-c <name>=<value>

Pass a configuration parameter to the command. The value given will override values from configuration files. The <name> is expected in the same format as listed by git config (subkeys separated by dots).

...

So I tried:
git -c safe.directory=/path/to/repo/owned/by/other/.git clone /path/to/repo/owned/by/other ./here

but I still get the dubious ownership error. I tried different variations of the above command but without success.
Thank you for your help.

Found an explanation and a solution at https://lore.kernel.org/all/ZqUc8DJ1uKcHYlcy@imp.flyn.org/T/ . The problem is that upload-pack doesn't have access to the config values passed to git -c, they must be explicitly passed to upload-pack. Try this:
git -c safe.directory=/path/to/repo/owned/by/other/.git clone -u 'git -c safe.directory="/path/to/repo/owned/by/other/.git" upload-pack' /path/to/repo/owned/by/other ./here

Can be simplified to
git -c safe.directory="*" clone -u 'git -c safe.directory="*" upload-pack' /path/to/repo/owned/by/other ./here

I tried and that works for me. If that doesn't work for you try the solution from https://lore.kernel.org/all/ZqZjRMqpEV_3WIkD@imp.flyn.org/ with upload-pack-safe shell script.

Thanks a lot @phd for digging out both the explanation and the solution. I could make it work with upload-pack; I did not need to use the upload-pack-safe shell script. One small correction to your answer though: -u is an option of git clone and not git, so in your commands the keyword clone should be before the -u.

@lige Tnx, fixed!

The command you used is almost right, but it has a slight syntax mistake. You need to apply the safe.directory setting to the main repository directory, not just the .git.
git -c safe.directory=/path/to/repo/owned/by/other clone /path/to/repo/owned/by/other ./here


I tried this syntax too and unfortunately it did not work either.

Try using absolute paths

Also make sure that you have the necessary permissions to access the repository

I tried with absolute paths. I also tried with a bare and a non-bare repository (both with and without the .git in the path when specifying safe.directory).  Still no luck... I do have the correct access permissions because I can clone the repository if I add its path to safe.directory in ~/.gitconfig.

You can temporarily point Git to a non-existent global config file -
GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=/dev/null git -c safe.directory=/path/to/repo/owned/by/other clone /path/to/repo/owned/by/other ./here

Another approach, ignoring ownership checks for this operation-
GIT_TEST_ASSUME_DIFFERENT_OWNER=true git clone /path/to/repo/owned/by/other ./here


I am not sure what you mean by "run clone command with --config" but I tried your command and unfortunately it did not work.

you can try second approach @lige

Thank you for the additional suggestion. No luck with the second approach either though. In fact, specifying GIT_TEST_ASSUME_DIFFERENT_OWNER=true actually does the opposite, it forces git to assume that you are not the owner of the repository even if you actually are (cf the git source code). So if this environment variable is set to TRUE then git will refuse to clone the repository even if it does belong to you.
